How can I react to click event on TextField composable? (no boilerplate code)
How can I react to click event on TextField composable without writing all this boilerplate code?
OutlinedTextField(
    value = ...,
    onValueChange = {},
    readOnly = true, // needed to avoid showing the keyboard
    // boilerplate code starts here
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
        .also { interactionSource ->
            LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
                interactionSource.interactions.collect {
                    if (it is PressInteraction.Release) {
                        // do what you want
                    }
                }
            }
        }
)

I found this solution here and it works for me since I don't need to handle the desktop scenario.
Since we are in 2024 I tried looking around for a simpler and more modern solution, but I found old posts only. Do I still have to write all this boilerplate code to achieve my goal?
